# Frequent Fan use and system slowdown on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, system, fan

I have noticed some frequent fan use with even the most minor tasks such as browsing the web or watching Youtube videos, the laptop has decent system specifications so it cannot be the reason. I also have windows 10 installed that I am dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 with and I have no issue when running windows, but as soon as I boot into Ubuntu the system starts to run the fans frequently and I notice an occasional slowdown with the the entire system. I would appreciate it if there was a way to find out why and to fix this issue with my system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very very likely due to your discrete graphics card not using proper drivers. It is powered on always and drawing power and so requiring the fan to run.

Try to turn off your secondary graphics card(other than the Intel one) from the BIOS and see if it's better. If you really need your graphics card to be used, consider installing appropriate drivers.

Comment: Hi the graphics card is an Nvidia 1050ti, and I am using the proprietary drivers for it.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried disabling it from the BIOS and then looking at the fan speed? I've seen even when proprietary drivers are used, there are significant problems with the graphics cards

Comment: Hey tried that, did not see an improvement, but I have fresh installed Ubuntu again and do not seem to be having any problem so far, thanks for your help